# How to simplify a symbolic and numeric mixed expression in Matlab

Tags: matlab, numeric, symbolic-math

I have a symbolic and numeric mixed expression:

> `(3145495418313256125*sin(11334310783410932061962315977/17437937757178560512000000000)*cos(theta))/85568392920039424`

where `theta` is a symbolic variable. I want to simplify this expression such that all the numeric numbers and their math operation results are changed to double.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of data types, you can't mix floating point and symbolic values. However, you can use variable precision arithmetic so that the values are represented in decimal form. Using [`vpa`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html):

```
syms theta
y1 = (3145495418313256125*sin(11334310783410932061962315977/17437937757178560512000000000)*cos(theta))/85568392920039424
y2 = vpa(y1)
```

which returns

```
y2 =

22.24607614528243677915796931637*cos(theta)
```

The data type (`class`) of `y2` is still `sym`. See the [`digits`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/digits.html) function to adjust the number of significant digits.

If you want to work in actual floating point you'll need to convert your symbolic expression into a function. You can automate that procedure by using the confusingly-named [`matlabFunction`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html):

```
thetafun = matlabFunction(y1)
```

which returns a function using double precision variables:

```
thetafun = 

@(theta)cos(theta).*2.224607614528244e1
```

The [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) `thetafun` can then be called just like any function, e.g., `thetafun(0.5)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `coeffs` command to achieve the desired:

```
f=2*cos(theta)/3+5*sin(theta)/19
c_f=coeffs(f);
fraction_c_f=double(c_f);

ans = [0.2632  0.6667]
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this answers the OPs question. `coeffs` is for polynomials, but the equation given is not a polynomial. Furthermore, I don't think that the OP was asking how to extract the symbolic values as is done with coefficients.

Comment: After thinking, ya, I actually agree.