# MATLAB Converting symbolic expressing to numeric via double

Tags: matlab, expression, symbolic-math

I am having a bit of an issue with my code and I can't find a good way to solve it. The issue seems to lie in the usage of double to convert a symbolic expression into a numeric expression that could be plotted using double.

Here is my code:

```
P1 = [-1.5, -2]
P2 = [2, 2]
P3 = [-2.5, 2.5]
P4 = [2, -1]

syms x 
syms y
c = 299792.458e3

r1i = sqrt((P1(1,1) - x)^2 + (P1(1,2) - y)^2)
r2i = sqrt((P2(1,1) - x)^2 + (P2(1,2) - y)^2)
t21 = -3.7294e-6
S = double(solve(t21 == (r2i-r1i)/c, y))
```

However, this produces the error:

```
Error using symengine
DOUBLE cannot convert the input expression into a double array.

Error in sym/double (line 613)
        Xstr = mupadmex('symobj::double', S.s, 0);

Error (line 18)
S = double(solve(sym(t21) == (r2i-r1i)/c, y))
```

I've done a bit of Googling, but I can't find any other site talking about a similar issue. Would anyone be able to assist me? Thank you so much for your time and help in advanced!

---

This question has been marked as a duplicate, but it doesn't quite fit the other identified link because I'm trying to plot the equation. It should produce two hyperbolas. None of the methods suggested help with the plotting

Comment: What is the output of `solve` in this case? I presume it is an expression that cannot be converted to numeric?

Comment: Solve by itself produces a very wonky expression - unfortunately too long for a comment, so I'll post a sample:
S =
 
 (19513152048714295248843753488567316317732864*x)/1742260830403368580231625282251030894361116619073 - (1319955730753333678201183*1742243756395325955223282543966728397959338602817^(1/2)*(- 5575186299632655785383929568162090376495104*x^2 + 2787593149816327892691964784081045188247552*x + 1742260481954224853190638695755432884230468088129)^(1/2))/4113797074956751557674031456059920847619007002023234187386458057211904 - 4878288012178573812210938372141829079433216/1742260830403

Comment: You need `vpa`.

Comment: How do you use vpa in this scenario?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to simplify a symbolic and numeric mixed expression in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22277525/how-to-simplify-a-symbolic-and-numeric-mixed-expression-in-matlab)

Comment: See the linked duplicate

Comment: That didn't quite work.
Using: 
y2 = vpa(S)
plot(y2)
I get the error:
Error using plot
Non-numeric data is not supported in 'Line'. The matlabFunction seems to also be symbolic as well

Comment: Your solution is a function of `x`. That means that there is no unique solution to the problem. And that makes sense, you have 2 variables but only one expression. But you should be able to plot `y` as a function of `x`.

Comment: Yes, I get that, but when doing something like:
S = solve(t21 == (r2i-r1i)/c, y)
Sfcn = matlabFunction(S)

z = linspace(-4,4)
figure
plot(z, Sfcn(z))
It produces two straight lines instead of hyperbolas as they should be